# Extraer datos xml de dominio externo con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, cors

resulta que tengo un error en el navegador al extraer los datos xml de un dominio externo a través de jquery ajax.

Trato de hacerlo de esta forma:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET" ,
     url: "http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=E8FBFBE1-E50F-4E6A-BEA7-CA2E41F96D0B&apikey=cf41bd17-7638-4c10-b869-341555a65d7f&type=xml&previous=yes&next=yes&cover=yes&callmeback=yes&defaultcover=yes" ,
dataType: "xml" ,   
 success: function(xml) {


    var title = $(xml).find('title').text(),  
    artist = $(xml).find('artists').text(); 



Actc(title, artist);


    }

});
```

Esa petición ajax la tengo dentro de un setinterval que actualiza los datos cada 20 segundos.

Va bien durante un rato, pero luego da este error en el navegador (Chrome) y deja de leer la información del xml:

*Failed to load http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=XXXXXXXX&apikey=xxxxxxx&callmeback=yes&type=xml&cover=yes&previous=yes: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost.canal' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.*

He buscado información pero no consigo aclararme. Según parece no es posible extraer con ajax contenido xml desde otro dominio diferente a no ser que se habilite CORS en mi servidor.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Aunque he intentado añadirlo a .httaccess sin éxito, ya que seguía dando el error. También he tratado de hacerlo mediante php pero también sin éxito. Seguramente hago algo mal, no soy muy experto en este sentido.

¿Cómo podría extraer los datos del xml sin problemas de CORS?

Comment: Si mal no me equivoco, el `.htaccess` con la configuración de habilitar el CORS va del lado del dominio externo, diciendole que le das permiso a que te hagan request de otro dominio.

Comment: Gracias por contestar @Kleith, he intentado añadir al htaccess de mi servidor <IfModule mod_headers.c>Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *</IfModule> y no hay ninguna diferencia, sigue dando el fallo.

Comment: No entiendo, porque configuras tu `htaccess` si quien no permite CORS es api.radionomy.com? Al parecer dicha API no permite solicitudes desde el browser

Comment: Segun el [foro](https://board.radionomy.com/viewtopic.php?f=86&t=298) las peticiones deberian ser desde tu servidor y no desde el browser

Answer (score 1):

Probá agregando estos headers al `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token"
  Header add Content-Type: "application/json"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Da Internal Server Error al agregarlo al htaccess, creo que eso es código php no?

Comment: Perdón, ahí lo corregí.

Comment: Nada, sigue sin funcionar :( También he intentado modificar wampserver con las soluciones que aportan aquí. Y nada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058104/enable-cors-with-wamp-on-windows-8 No funciona ni en wampserver, ni en el servidor externo que tengo

Comment: Por ahí es con jQuery Ajax, intentá cambiando el Allow Headers por `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "x-requested-with"`.

Comment: He modificado eso y sigue igual.